# Slow BIOS after Debian install

Tags: debian, bios

I installed Debian (recent 2019 version) into a AMD 64 computer, running 8 GB mem and 128 GB ssd disk. Since then the BIOS is really slow and the computer hangs there, making it almost impossible to install another OS.
Anyone recognize a problem similar to this one?

Answer (score 1):

If this is a server-grade system, or otherwise the BIOS includes a feature to redirect BIOS & bootloader input/output to a serial port (either a real one, or a remote console processor like iLO/iLOM/IRMC/DRAC/etc.), then activating that feature but not specifying a high serial port speed might cause exactly that kind of slowness. If such a feature was activated for a real serial port with hardware handshaking enabled but nothing actually connected to the port, the lack of handshaking signals might even cause a total stoppage of output until a timeout is reached.

Reloading the BIOS defaults would probably have disabled the redirection feature and so returned things to normal, matching your experience.

Normally, the BIOS utility menus are designed with the assumption that screen redraws are essentially instant. But if the VGA text-mode output is redirected to a serial port working with 9600 bps speed, that assumption will be very much untrue.

When using a virtual serial port, using the highest commonly available serial transfer speed of 115200 bps is usually not a problem, however some remote console processors may have limitations there. But even on the slowest virtual serial port implementations I've seen, the speed of 38400 bps has been available.

The difference between 9600 bps and 115200 bps can be enough to change the BIOS utility access from "is it hanging or just extremely slow?" to "usable but a bit slow".

Older systems with a remote console processor might require Java for the KVM remote console functionality, which can be troublesome because of the security requirements of new Java JRE packages. Newer remote console processors have started offering HTML5-based KVM remote consoles, which no longer need Java.

Many remote console processors will also support a SSH character-based connection and a virtual serial port. Since Linux TTY devices are essentially serial ports or emulations of them, Linux can easily be configured to use a serial port as its console device, which fits in nicely with a remote console processor that provides such access. This allows robust Java-free administrative access to the system even in the event of problems or misconfiguration of the main network interface(s).

But the Linux console access only works after the kernel has started up - and having access to Linux bootloader to specify boot parameters to the kernel can be an important part of troubleshooting. To fix that, the bootloader must also be accessible through a virtual serial port. This can be done in one of two ways: either by explicitly configuring the bootloader to use a serial port (GRUB has facilities for that) or by activating the BIOS text-mode I/O redirection to serial port, if such a feature is available. The latter option will also provide BIOS boot messages to the serial-based remote console, which can be useful in case of hardware problems.

Some HP systems will allow switching the BIOS utility menus into a command-line mode for low-speed access, which might also help. But you would have to do that before activating the KVM I/O redirection to a serial port.

Answer (score 0):

After waiting for 20 minutes, the BIOS utility finally became active. I loaded Bios Defaults, re-arranged Boot order and was finally able to get control of the machine again.
Hopefully this helps someone.